# Illegal start of type - Brackets

Tags: java

The error I get for this code: is illegal start of type.

I can't figure out where to place brackets in the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; public class TaxCalculator {
public static void main(String [] args)
{   
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your income?");
    double income; //Income 
    income = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("How many dependents are in your household?");
    int dependents; //Dependents
    dependents = keyboard.nextInt();
}
public static void sd();
int singleyes = 5950;
int singleno = 11900;
boolean single = true;
if (single = yes) 
        StandardDeduction = 'yes';
    } else if (single = no) {
        StandardDeduction = 'no'; }
```

Comment: Your method declaration for `sd()` almost looks like a C/C++ function prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sd` method declaration is incorrect. Boolean is never `yes` or `no` and `String`(s) are surrounded by double quotes. This

```
public static void sd();
```

should be something like

```
public static String sd() {
    int singleyes = 5950;
    int singleno = 11900;
    boolean single = true;
    if (single) { 
        StandardDeduction = "yes";
    } else {
        StandardDeduction = "no";
    } 
}
```

Finally, the semi-colon acts as a no-op statement and can't appears outside a statement body.